# How can I create a fully dynamic table from dynamic JSON output?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I need to be able to build a HTML table from JSON created - dynamically - by a function that outputs JSON Objects. However, I have no clue what the keys and values are in advance, therefore I cannot create table headers and cells until I get the data. As an example, this is the function that outputs the JSON - to explain why I do not know the keys and values:

```
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    echo "{";
    echo '"aaData" : [';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $ContentCount; $i++)
    {
        echo '{ '; 
        for ($j = 0; $j < $HeadCount; $j++)
        {

            echo '"' .$Headers[$j][name] .'" : "' . $Content[$i][$Headers[$j][name]] . '"';
            if ($j != $HeadCount - 1) { echo ","; }

        }
        echo ' }';
        if ($i != $ContentCount - 1) { echo ","; }  
    }
    echo "] }";
```

This function creates a valid JSON object formatted for DataTables, although it's being used for custom work. What I want to know is how to read the key and value pairs so I can build up a table (or another format) based on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example

```
var dimensions = [{ width: 11, height: 15, length: 20 },{ width: 12, height: 15, length: 20 },{ width: 13, height: 15, length: 20 }];

var keys = $.map( dimensions[0], function( value, key ) {
  return key;
});
$('#DynTbl').append('<table id="dt" border=1><tr id="dth"></tr></table>');

$.each(keys, function(key,value) {
    $('#dth').append('<th>'+value+'</th>');
});


$.each(dimensions, function(index,data) {

$('#dt').append('<tr id="t'+index+'"></tr>');

var values = $.map( data, function( value, key ) {
  return value;
});

$.each(values, function(key,value) {
    $('#t'+index).append('<td>'+value+'</td>');
});
});
```

check at http://jsfiddle.net/rajumjib/cA5LW/4/
change

```
var dimensions = [{ width: 11, height: 15, length: 20 },{ width: 12, height: 15, length: 20 },{ width: 13, height: 15, length: 20 }];
```

and try

Comment: That actually did it perfectly! I had to tweak things a little for it to work, but that pairs with my system.

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved by using $.map.

Example: Map the original object to a new array and double each value.

```
var dimensions = { width: 10, height: 15, length: 20 };
dimensions = $.map( dimensions, function( value, index ) {
  return value * 2;
});
```

Result:

```
[ 20, 30, 40 ]
```

Example: Map an object's keys to an array.

```
var dimensions = { width: 10, height: 15, length: 20 };
var keys = $.map( dimensions, function( value, key ) {
  return key;
});
```

Result:

```
[ "width", "height", "length" ]
```

Read more at [https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)